# Should I tell players the difficulty of checks?

Tags: difficulty-class, tails-of-equestria

I'll be running [*Tails of Equestria*](https://riverhorse.eu/our-games/my-little-pony-tails-of-equestria/) with my daughter and her friend soon. (For reference, I've previously played D&D 5e before and DMed it a little, including with children.)

Should the PCs be told the difficulty of checks they make?

I never would in D&D, and the main reason I'm wondering whether it's done in TOE is the sections on Exploding Hoof and ponies helping each other.

Comment: @DaleM in D&D I've never been told it as a player, so I never did, I guess!

Comment: @JamesWilson just so you know, there’s no rule against it - some tables play with secret DCs and some play open and some mix and match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You should tell players the difficulty of checks.

Ordinarily when there isn't an explicit callout of how it's done, this is the sort of thing an extended sample of play would make clear about the authors' intent. There isn't much of one in the corebook, but what there is:

> The Unicorn could then ask, "Can I use my Telekinesis talent to try to turn the key in the lock?"
>
> The gamemaster could say, "Sure, that is a test against a Difficulty of 3 for your Telekinesis, which is a D6."
>
> -- "Tests & Challenges", p.55

does seem to indicate that the GM should be mentioning the test difficulty along with the attribute.

Also, making decisions to spend 1, 2, or 3 friendship on a check if you fail it gets a lot harder if you don't know the difficulty, and thus how likely it is that you can succeed on a reroll or using a d20.